# How to create a dynamic javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to create dynamic object in angularJs.

I have a input object like below,

```
$scope.inputObj={
  formName:"regForm", //this will be dynamic
  fields:[]
}
```

i need to create a object with name "regForm" (this name will be dynamic).

Output should look like:

```
$scope.regForm={}; //here form name should be created as json object
```

Comment: `$scope[$scope.inputObj.formName]={}`

Comment: thank you very much. Your help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create dynamic property names inside object you must use `[]` notation instead of `dot`.

As you've mentioned `$scope.inputObj.formName` will be containing the name of property.

So, now to create new object with that property in scope:

```
$scope[$scope.inputObj.formName] = {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valid support